# Plot non-numeric data

Tags: r, plot

How do we plot a non-numeric data in R? I want to plot (using any graph type - for example, boxplot or histogram ... etc) `aa` against `bb` . I want to have `bb` on my x-axis and `aa` on my y-axis.

```
class(aa)
# [1] "character"
class(bb)
# [1] "character"
```

Comment: How about providing some data?

Comment: @Brown After re-reading you question, I am not sure I gave you what you are looking for.  Do you want, for each type, a separate bar for each name ?  In other words, do you want the count of each `type` ? Can you give an example output data frame with which column(s) you want on the x-axis and y-axis ?  I will delete my answer soon until this clarified or someone else answers it. If it is what you want, I will modify my answer to address your comments.

Comment: @Brown There are two ways to interpret what you said.  The easiest way to answer my question is to look at the contents of `df_summary` in my answer and let me know if that is the table you would expect (i.e. counts per each type).  If so, then my answer covers what you asked.

Comment: Can you test the code anyway.  This is not an error, it is telling you that functions in `dplyr` have the same name as other packages and that the `dplyr` will be called if you don't explicitly specify the package.  For example, if you call `filter`, `dplyr::filter` will be used now.  If you want the version in the `stats` package you will have to specify `stats::filter`.  This can be annoying but it happens that multiple packages have the same function names.

Comment: @Brown You don't really want to get rid of them as you have to be careful in this situation (i.e. when using multiple packages in R, that share the same function names).  This is really a different question and you may want to google this question, as I am sure many of your questions have been answered on this (most likely in SO too).

Comment: @Brown I can add a few things but you should look for tutorials on the following items `base` R plotting, `ggplot`, `dplyr` and / or `data.table`, `tidyr` and `stringr`.  It sounds like a lot but these are some key packages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr` and `ggplot` for this.

Assuming the input you provided is in `df` (see bottom of this post for input data)

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)

## Assuming the data is in the file 'Types.csv'
df <- read.csv('Types.csv')

df_summary <-
    df                          %>% # Pipe df into group_by
    group_by(type)              %>% # grouping by 'type' column
    summarise(name_count = n())     # calculate the name count for each group
## 'df_summary' now contains the summary data for each 'type'
df_summary

##     type name_count
##    (chr)      (int)
##1     dos          6
##2  normal          1
##3   probe          4
##4     r2l          8
##5     u2r          4
##6 unknown          1

### Two ways to plot using ggplot

## (1) Plot pre summarized data: 'df_summary'.
ggplot(df_summary, aes(type, name_count)) +  # 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity')              # stat='identity' is used for summarized data.

## (2) Bar plot on original data frame (not summarised)
ggplot(df, aes(type))      +
    geom_bar()             + # 'stat' isn't needed here.
    labs(y = 'name_count')
```

Here is the plot of `df_summary`

[image]

You can also do the following to add labels and a plot title (plot results not shown for this

```
ggplot(df, aes(type)) +
    geom_bar() +
    labs(x = 'Type', y = 'Count') +
    ggtitle('Type Counts')
```

To add text labels just above the bars (in this case, of the frequencies of each category), adding `geom_text` can be used as below (plot results not shown).

```
ggplot(df_summary, aes(type, name_count)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    geom_text(aes(label = name_count), vjust = -1) +
    ggtitle('Type Counts')

## OR

ggplot(df, aes(type)) +
    geom_bar() +
    labs(x = 'Type', y = 'Count') +
    geom_text(stat = 'count', aes(label = ..count..), vjust = -1) +
    ggtitle('Type Counts')
```

Input data

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
         name    type
           back     dos
buffer_overflow     u2r
      ftp_write     r2l
   guess_passwd     r2l
           imap     r2l
        ipsweep   probe
           land     dos
     loadmodule     u2r
       multihop     r2l
        neptune     dos
           nmap   probe
           perl     u2r
            phf     r2l
            pod     dos
      portsweep   probe
        rootkit     u2r
          satan   probe
          smurf     dos
            spy     r2l
       teardrop     dos
    warezclient     r2l
    warezmaster     r2l
         normal  normal
        unknown unknown')
```

Comment: @Brown The `%>%` operator is a pipe operator.  I will put more comments in the answer.

Comment: @Brown You could try something like `ggplot(df_summary, aes(type, name_count)) +  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + geom_text(aes(label = name_count), position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -1)`.  I will add this to the solution if this works for you.

Comment: @Brown For different colors for your bars, you should do something like `ggplot(df_summary, aes(type, name_count, fill = type))`.  When you use `fill` you will also get a legend with it.  If you google for coloring bars in barplots, you will likely find a number of helpful SO suggestions (like specifying colors of your choice).

Comment: @Brown The reason your bars were all `darkblue` is that the `fill="darkblue"` in `geom_bar` sets all bars to the same color.  If you want the bar colors to be different, as shown in my previous comment, you can set the `fill` in `aes` to map it to a variable (`type` in this case).

Comment: yes that is true. We can also edit the default legend title and a whole lot of changes which is cool. I can calculate the percentage of each frequency and print it but can we add the percentage to the text labels above the bar? For example: something like 120(35%) - which means the frequency (`name_count`) in our case and 35% is the percentage out of the total. Having the total of each frequency on each bar and what percentage it is would be nice. can we?

Comment: @Brown You can try one of two things, either modify `name_count` to have the value you want (e.g. `120(35%)`) or create a new column with this value.  If the new column is called `count_pct`, you would use this in place of `name_count` in `geom_text`.  Give it a try, it should be close to what you need.

Comment: yes I tried that since we have 6 `name_count` - how can we use it in geom_text?