# Plotting non-numerical categorical data in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for ideas on how to plot a data set of 100 samples in ggplot structured as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(sample = c(1:5), 
                 group = c("class 1", "class 1", "class 3", "class 3", "class 3"),
                 cat_1 = c("D", "Mj", "Mj", "Tr", "Mn"),
                 cat_2 = c("D", "-", "Mn", "Tr", "Mj"),
                 cat_3 = c("Mn", "Tr", "D", "Tr", "Mn"),
                 cat_4 = c("-", "-", "Mj", "-", "Mn"))
```

The number of samples per group varies.
I have 20 different categories (i.e. cat_1 ... cat_20) and 6 groups in my actual data.

D is greater than 50% of a particular category.
Mj is between 5% and 50%.
Mn is between 1% and 5%,
Tr is less than 1%.
Not observed in the sample is denoted "-".

[Plot non-numeric data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984132/plot-non-numeric-data) provides some ideas. Essentially I want to show the breakdown of categories by group. I am seeking inspired plots for a scientific report. I was thinking of a doughnut plot for each group with the number of samples in each group in the middle of the doughnut. However, this is hard to interpret at one level. I need to honour the data.

This is the best I can do so far:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(3:6), names_to = "category") %>%
  group_by(group, category) %>%
  mutate(count = n(),
         value = ifelse(value == "-", NA, value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  ggplot(aes(value, fill = category)) +
  geom_bar() +
  xlab("abundance") +
  facet_wrap(~ group)`
```

Comment: So you have 6 groups with 20 variables. I would recommend CIRCULAR STACKED BARCHART (https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/circular-barplot.html). I would separate each variable by six "classes". The distribution of values in each BAR will clearly show the differences between classes.  I would also recommend to plot proportion of each value in variable, so no problems with different numbers of samples.

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a whirl and post my results!

Comment: Don't want to get into any fight about visualization, but probably any kind of circular plot (e.g. pie chart) is bad. You won't be able to visually compare all your categories. Rather do a simple bar chart and then maybe give you groups a different colour.

Comment: I am inclined to go with bar charts. My issue is that I do not know how to normalise my categorical data. Any help with that would be appreciated.

Comment: `geom_bar()` does normalise automatically, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(3:6), names_to = "category") %>%
  group_by(group, category) %>%
  mutate(count = n(),
         value = ifelse(value == "-", NA, value)) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  ggplot(aes(value, fill = category)) +
  geom_bar(colour = "black", lwd = 0.2) +
  xlab("abundance") +
  facet_wrap(~ group, ncol = 1) + 
  theme_bw()
```